# Doubts about memory allocation good practices

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

Let's say I have a struct with a declaration similar to this

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int age;
    double *numbers; // A pointer to a list of doubles
} Person;
```

And let's say I have an "initialising" function `Person_new` that creates a new `Person`, that takes `char *name`, `int age` and `double *numbers` as parameters, allocates memory for the new `Person` and assigns the value of its parameters to the correspondent elements of the new `Person`.

```
Person *Person_new(char *name, int age, double *numbers) {
    Person *self;
    self = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    if (self != NULL) {
        self->name = name;
        self->age = age;
        self->numbers = numbers;
    } 
    return self;
}
```

What would be the correct way of using this function? Should it also be allocating memory for the elements of the struct? What I have understood about this is that since `age` is not a pointer I should not allocate any other memory for that (since I `malloc` it when `malloc`ing `self`). Hence I should allocate some memory for the other two parameters because with my function I have allocated memory just for their pointers. So, should this `malloc`s be made from the person utilising the function or from the function itself?

Comment: It depends on whether you want to store the pointers provided to the function, or make copies of the data which they point to. Your code does the former. If you want to copy the data use `malloc` or `strdup`. For example, if you are parsing a text file and pass pointers to the input buffer data, you will need to make a copy of that data because the line buffer will get overwritten. But if you are passing string literals to the function, you can just store the pointer as given.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't know enough to be able to critically analyze, what are the pros and cons of the two approaches? If I just kept the pointers and then the function's user changed what they point to, wouldn't that make everything blow up?

Comment: @Giuppox It's all depends on what you want to do.... Your function is fine for some use cases and wrong for others... So we can't really give you an answer.

Comment: OT: How do you know how many doubles there are in the memory that `numbers` point to....

Comment: @4386427 In my real implementation there was another `int` parameter with that information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, designing data structures that rely on "soft copies" is a bad idea. That is, you aren't actually making a "hard copy" of the data passed, you are just pointing at it and the actual allocation is done elsewhere. Which is problematic for many reasons - that data might turn invalid, for example.

There are scenarios where "soft copy" might make sense, such as making a container pointing at read-only data like string literals. But generally if you are making a container with read/write access, you should make a copy of all values passed so that the container "owns" all the memory it uses.

In your case you seem to be doing some simple database, in which case you should definitely allocate copies of the data passed. Generally the part of the code doing the allocation is also responsible for freeing it, so you will also need to provide a clean-up function.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking what you said is correct (no need to allocate `age` twice, and allocation for `name` and `numbers` is needed).

However, if you're willing to impose length restriction on those fields, I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    int age;
    double numbers[MAX_NUMBERS_LENGTH];
} Person;
```

In this case, when you `malloc` this struct, the memory for `name` and `numbers` is allocated as well. Then, in your `Person_new` function you can copy the `name` and `numbers` values from the pointers you received to the fields of the struct, for example using `memcpy`.
This way, all the memory used by the struct is owned by the struct, which could prevent potential issues (what if the memory for `numbers` or `name` is freed while the struct is still in use?). This also means that when you free a `Person` the memory for its fields will be freed as well, which is also a good behavior IMO.

Answer (score 1):

> Should it also be allocating memory for the elements of the struct?

There is no "one size fits all" answer to this.

It depends on what your program is doing, e.g. where is data coming from and how was that data read into the system.

As an example the data could come from a file that was read by some other function which called your `Person_new` whenever a "person" was read from the file. In such case it's likely that the file-reader function already used dynamic allocation while reading the name and the numbers. If so, it will make no sense to allocate memory inside `Person_new` and copy all the data again. Instead it's fine to simply store the pointers to the "already allocated" memory.

When you write a function, you always need to describe what the function is doing and describe the rules for calling the function, i.e. make a contract. It's fine to write that `name` and `numbers` must be pointers to memory obtained using `malloc` and that ownership is transferred as part of calling your function. (The no-standard but widely used `strdup` is an example of transferring ownership of allocated memory).

But notice that this limits the way your function can be used. For instance your function can't be used with pointers to arrays with automatic storage duration (i.e. local variables) and worse: If someone breaks your contract and do pass a pointer to a local variable, it's a bug that can't be detected by the compiler.

If your function allocates memory and copies data, you don't need to set such limitations on how your function may be called.

On the other hand, if the "must be pointers to dynamic allocated memory" limitation is fine for your use case, you may avoid unneeded allocations and data copies.

So - just to repeat - there is no single solution that fits all use cases - it depends on the rest of your program.